# Where can Gaussian Elimination be used?

Tags: linear-algebra, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, big-list, gaussian-elimination

I have searched for this and came to know about it that it is traditionally used to solve linear equations, finding determinant, rank of matrix, inverse of matrix.

There was a problem on codechef: given few numbers, choose some of them to have xor value of all those no.s to be maximum?
The gaussian elimination technique could be used there.

I want to know, what are such other nice and un-tradional, unknown examples, applications, scenarios where this technique can be used?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lights_Out_%28game%29

Comment: I've written a detailed explanation for lights out for a German competition:http://www.bundeswettbewerb-informatik.de/uploads/media/loesungshinweise301_01.pdf - page 20